# For which value of $\Omega$ I have a sufficient and necessary condition?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The variables $X$, $Y$, $v$ and $\Omega$ are positive. $X$ and $Y$ are bounded, i.e., $X\in(0,X_{max}]$ and $Y\in(0,Y_{max}]$.

I would like to find a sufficient and necessary condition on

$$
\left(1+2X^2\right)\left(1+2Y^2\right)\geq\Omega
$$
More precisely, the question is: For which $\Omega$ as a function of $v_1$ and $v_2$ (probably as a function of $X_{max}$ and $Y_{max}$ also?) we have:
$$
X\geq v_1\text{ and } Y\geq v_2 \iff \left(1+2X^2\right)\left(1+2Y^2\right)\geq\Omega
$$

---

Attempt:

I have: if $X\geq v_1$ and $Y\geq v_2$ for some positive $v_1$ and $v_2$ then 
$$
\left(1+2X^2\right)\left(1+2Y^2\right)\geq\left(1+2v_1^2\right)\left(1+2v_2^2\right)
$$
then I choose $\Omega=\left(1+2v_1^2\right)\left(1+2v_2^2\right)$.

But if 
$$
\left(1+2X^2\right)\left(1+2Y^2\right)\geq\left(1+2v_1^2\right)\left(1+2v_2^2\right)
$$

I cannot say that $X\geq v_1$ and $Y\geq v_2$?

I tried to see what happens using MATALB:

```
syms x y
ezsurf( (1+2*x^2)*(1+2*y^2), [0, 100, 0, 100] )
```

So I get this:

[image]

I think I can get what I want but how? In the figure we see that if 
$$
\left(1+2X^2\right)\left(1+2Y^2\right)\geq\Omega
$$
Then, $X$ and $Y$ must be greater than something, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $\Omega >  1$, the boundary of the region $(1+2x^2)(1+2y^2) \ge \Omega$ in the $xy$ plane is formed by the curve $(1+2x^2)(1+2y^2) = \Omega$. In particular, this curve passes through the points $(0,\sqrt{2\Omega-2}/2)$, $(\sqrt{2\Omega-2}/2,0)$ and $(\sqrt{2\sqrt{\Omega}-2}/2, \sqrt{2\sqrt{\Omega}-2}/2)$.  The curve is, well, curvy: no segment of it is a straight line.
Thus the region is certainly **not** of the form $\{(x,y): x \ge v_1, \; y \ge v_2\}$.  Here's what the region does look like (in the case $\Omega=2$, $X_{max} = Y_{max} = 1$).

[image]

Of course, if you restrict to the intervals $x \in [0,X_{max}]$ and $y \in [0,Y_{max}]$ there are some trivial cases: if $\Omega > (1+2X_{max}^2)(1+2Y_{max}^2)$, there are no such $x$ and $y$ satisfying the inequality, so you could take $v_1 > X_{max}$ or $v_2 > Y_{max}$

On the other hand, if $\Omega \le 1$ we always have $(1+2x^2)(1+2y^2) \ge \Omega$ for any real $x,y$.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I understand right, for $\Omega>1$, I can take $\Omega>\left(1+2X_{max}^2\right)\left(1+2Y_{max}^2\right)$ to have a necessary and sufficient condition? In the graph in the question, If $\left(1+2X^2\right)\left(1+2Y^2\right)\geq\Omega$ then there exists $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that $X>v_1$ and $Y>v_2$, no?

Comment: Can I say this ? If $\left(1+2X^2\right)\left(1+2Y^2\right)\geq\Omega$ then $\exists v_1, v_2$ such that $X>v_1$ and $Y>v_2$.